# AS3 blurring lines using graphics.linestyle

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a rookie to AS3 and i'm creating a small painting application. If I wanted to apply a blur affect to lines drawn, how would i go about that?

graphics.lineStyle(size, color, alpha);

as you can see there is no parameter for it, any help? Thanks

Comment: Attach a blur filter to whatever object you're adding linestyle to.

Answer (score 0):

You got to use the BlurFilter in order to blur graphics.

```
var myFilter:BitmapFilter = new BlurFilter(10, 10, BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH);
var lineFilters:Array = new Array();
lineFilters.push(myFilter);

lineContainer.filters = lineFilters;
```

As far as I know, it is not possible to apply filter to lines or graphics, only containers.

**EDIT:**
Test program:

```
var lineContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();

lineContainer.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
lineContainer.graphics.lineStyle(5);
lineContainer.graphics.lineTo(150,150);
lineContainer.graphics.endFill();

addChild(lineContainer);

var myFilter:BitmapFilter = new BlurFilter(10,10,BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH);
var lineFilters:Array = new Array();
lineFilters.push(myFilter);

lineContainer.filters = lineFilters;
```

Comment: I think this is actually what I need, but can you explain what the code means so I can change it to my custom use?

Comment: All you need to do is put the lines in a different container, for example the lineContainer is a sprite, you draw in lineContainer.graphics, after every draw, you just re-apply the filter above. (run the last line again)

Comment: One more thing, I thought I had it, but I have encountered a problem. if I was going to adjust the blur using a slider, could I not just use      var myFilter:BitmapFilter = new BlurFilter(blurSlider.value, blurSlider.value, BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH);   ? Because this doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure what blurSlider.value is, but it must be a number. lineContainer.filters = lineFilters; line SETS the filter actually, not the instantiating.

Comment: Well blurSlider.value is getting the value of a slider -- which is named blurSlider. I was hoping to adjust the level of blur, so when the slider is set to 0 the xblur and yblur would also equal 0. But this doesn't work, can you think of a workaround?

Comment: If you don't apply the new filter to the container, then it of course not work.

Comment: Okay so is there a way to update the filter each time the slider is changed? I am very new to as3 and I dont know many things, but I have a basic understanding. I need to apply the new filter every time the slider is moved -- but I dont know how to do that

Comment: Yes there is.. blurSlider.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeBlurFilter);

Comment: Okay, well thank you for all your help, although it still didn't work. It makes all the lines drawn on the board blur --  instead of future drawn lines blurred -- I understand why it doesnt work, but you have helped so much I will find some other way to figure it out